# Sequence data base with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am learning Django and creating  a Biological Sequence database, contains hundreds of sequences using a model as given bellow, model has two fields,  "Seq_ID" and "sequence". I am trying to write a view so that it can render IDs of all the sequences on home page and clicking on a particular IDs it will shows the associated sequence.

**Updated Views and Urls:**

Model:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

    # Create your models here.
class FastaSeq(models.Model):

    Seq_ID =  models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Sequense = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):

        return self.Seq_ID
```

View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings 
from .models import FastaSeq

def home(request):
    data = FastaSeq.objects.all()
    context = {'data':data}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def single(request,Seq_ID):
    data = FastaSeq.objects.get(Seq_ID=Seq_ID)
    return render(request,template,{'data':data})
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from new_app import views as new_app_view



urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/', new_app_view.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^User/(?P<Seq_ID>\d+)/$', new_app_view.single, name='single'), 

]
```

Example_Data:

```
Seq_ID:
>01_sequence

Sequence:
LARALLLCAAVVCGAANPCCSHPCQNRGVCMSVGFDQYKCDCTRTGFYGENCTTPEFLTRIKLLLKPTP
DTVHYILTHFKGVWNIVNKISFLRNMIMRYVLTSRSHLIESPPTYNVHYSYKSWEAFSNLSYYTRALPPV
PDDCPTPMGVKGRKELPDSKEVVKKVLLRRKFIPDPQGTNLMFAFFAQHFTHQFFKTDIERGPAFTKGKN
HGVDLSHVYGESLERQHNRRLFKDGKMKYQMINGEMYPPTVKDTQVEMIYPPHIPEHLKFAVGQEVFGLV
```

Using this model I have added around 50 Demo sequences into the database but not able to writedown a view which can show the sequence ID on home page and clicking on ID will land you on sequence data.

**Updated:**

Showing some Error:

```
No    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/home/jai/.virtualenvs/env1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 389, in _reverse_with_prefix
    (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'single' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['User/(?P<Seq_ID>\\d+)/$']
[06/Jul/2017 06:46:13] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 500 133824
```

Comment: @np.array I know HTML, CSS and little bit Javascript also but want to learn Django concepts.

Answer (score 2):

```
from .models import FastaSeq
def home(request):
    data = FastaSeq.objects.all()
    context = {'data':data}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

in template

```
{% for d in data %}
<a href="{% url 'single' d.Seq_ID %}">{{ d.Seq_ID  }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

in urls.py

```
url(r'^User/(?P<Seq_ID>[\w{}.-]{1,40})/$', 'views.single', name='single'),
```

create another view

```
def single(request,Seq_ID):
    data = FastaSeq.objects.get(Seq_ID=Seq_ID)
    return render(request,template,{'data':data})
```

in `single` function template`

```
{{ data.Seq_ID }}
{{ data.Sequense }}
```

Comment: I am trying with your suggestion but its ended with an error which I have updated in main body of the Question. thanks

Comment: change this line <a href="{% url 'single' Seq_ID %}">{{ d.Seq_ID  }}</a>

to <a href="{% url 'single' d.Seq_ID %}">{{ d.Seq_ID  }}</a> in your template

Comment: Its showing error again: "Reverse for 'single' with arguments '(u'>NP_001009432.',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['User/(?P<Seq_ID>\\d+)/$']".. :(

Comment: try the edited url, its just a problem with url regex, i dont know a lot of regex but see if this helps @jax

Comment: @ Exprator  wer are providing two variable to our view function  "def single(request, Seq_ID)", kindly explain how this view function getting Seq_ID values during function call..

Comment: when you are clicking on the a tag it consists of the id can you see? that id is being passed to this function.

Comment: It means if I will click on this link "<a href="{% url 'single' d.Seq_ID %}">{{ d.Seq_ID  }}</a>,  value d.Seq_ID would be passed to function as Seq_ID. Sorry if I am asking silly Questions but my mind got exhausted since morning I am trying to solve Django error.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `seq_id`s to the context:

```
context = {'seq_ids': FastaSeq.objects.all()}
```

Then iterate through them in your template.

```
{% for id in seq_ids %}
    <your html here>
{% endfor %}
```